# Google Maps API LatLng NaN

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm struggling with the Google Maps JavaScript API v3. I need to create a new `LatLng` object with some specific coordinates. According to the [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=de#LatLng) this one should simply do the trick:

```
 myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -34, lng: 151});
```

Currently doing so simply creates the desired object but with values representing `NaN`. So no matter what I'm doing, I can't create a proper `LatLng` object and even the docs aren't helping me much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLng) constructor takes two numbers as arguments, not a [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#LatLngLiteral).

```
myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: -34, lng: 151});
```

should be:

```
myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151);
```

In many cases you can use a google.maps.LatLngLiteral **instead** of a google.maps.LatLng.

```
myLatLng = {lat: -34, lng: 151};
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34, 151);
  var myLatLng2 = {
    lat: -34.05,
    lng: 151
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng2,
    map: map
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```